# Why is header box element out of body box element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to finish home project and I am stuck with header element box not being within body box element. Can you explain to me why is that happening and how to fix it?

```css
* {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: seashell;
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-family: Helvetica, 'Times New Roman', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}

header {
  height: 69px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--Fixed header-->
  <header>
    <img src="resources/tea-cozy-logo.png" alt="logo of a tea company" />
    <div class="navigation">
      <a href="#mission">Mission</a>
      <a href="#featuredtea">Featured Tea</a>
      <a href="#locations">Locations</a>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Because it's not connected to the `body` due its `position: fixed`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed

Comment: change your header position to relative and do style top:0px for your header. better way is using bootstrap fix header https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Comment: There is one more problem with your CSS. For `display: inline`, the `width` and the `hight` properties have no effect, because inline elements don't have a formal box with which to apply the styles.